Rcpp incorrect subscript out of bounds warning
I get a subscript out of bounds warning, but the function seems to work fine and I don't see why the warning occurs. Here is a minimal example:
NumericVector foo(double seed, int steps) {
  NumericVector result;
  result.push_back(seed);
  for (int i = 1; i <= steps; ++i) {
    result.push_back(result[i-1] + seed);
  }
  return result;
}

I'm using Rcpp 1.0.13, the function is in a package.
Calling the function with foo(2.5, 3) gives warnings
1: In foo(2.5, 3) : subscript out of bounds (index 0 >= vector size 0)
2: In foo(2.5, 3) : subscript out of bounds (index 1 >= vector size 0)
3: In foo(2.5, 3) : subscript out of bounds (index 2 >= vector size 0)

Why do the warnings appear?

When I compile your version, I have no such warning. foo(2.5,3) returns a vector c(2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0).  Maybe you have another function foo() shadowing this C++ function.(Also, don't push_back into Rcpp::NumericalVector. Use a std::vector<double> instead.  You can return it too, and it has better growth performance.  This is documented in the Rcpp docs.)

Thank you, I cannot replicate the warning any more after a complete restart of the system. Seems like some system state was off.
